# How does terraform share namespace across tfstate files?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm building out my infra using terraform and based on some advice that I read on a few blogs like [this one](https://getbetterdevops.io/terraform-create-infrastructure-in-multiple-environments/#), I decided to separate environments by folder instead of using a workspace.

I'm currently using an S3 backend to manage my state. I've listed a pared down version of the file structure and files below. In order to do deploy code, I effectively use:

```
cd /
for m in $(find . -name "main.tf" | xargs dirname); do
  terraform -chdir=$m init -backend-config=../../backend.hcl
  terraform -chdir=$m apply
done
```

However, when I ran it as is, the staging configuration kept attempting to overwrite the prod configuration. Specifically, I expected that `module.webserver.aws_instance.main` would be stored in separate state files and refer to completely separate instances. However, after running `terraform -chdir=prod/webserver apply`, `terraform -chdir=staging/webserver apply` attempted to replace the prod instance with its own.

How is this happening? Shouldn't the state file effectively create independent namespaces for each environment?

I've worked around this quite easily as you can simply rename the module in each environment, but it doesn't seem like you'd need to.

```
File Structure:
/:
 - backend.hcl
/global/s3:
 - main.tf
/prod/webserver:
 - main.tf
/staging/webserver:
 - main.tf
/modules/webserver:
 - main.tf
```

```
# /global/s3/main.tf:
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key = "global/s3/terraform.tfstate"
  }
  ...
}

...

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state" {
  bucket = "some-terraform-state"
}

...

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "terraform_locks" {
  name = "terraform-locks"
  hash_key = "LockID"

  ...
}
```

```
# /prod/webserver/main.tf:
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key = "prod/webserver/terraform.tfstate"
  }

  ...
}

...

module "webserver" {
  source = "../../modules/webserver"
  env = "prod"
}
```

```
# /staging/webserver/main.tf:
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key = "staging/webserver/terraform.tfstate"
  }

  ...
}

...

module "webserver" {
  source = "../../modules/webserver"
  env = "staging"
}
```

```
# /module/webserver/main.tf:
...

resource "aws_instance" "main" {
  ...
}

...
```

Comment: First I want to point out that you wouldn't be encountering this problem if you had used Workspaces. As to your problem, please edit your question to show exactly how you are running `terraform apply`. Specifically which folder(s) are you running that command in?

Comment: Done.

As for workspaces,  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Different resources I've read recommended different approaches. 

Just see the debate here: 
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/t51869/is_it_best_practice_to_use_workspaces_or/ 
- https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/15300/terraform-workspaces-vs-isolated-directories#:~:text=Therefore%2C%20as%20described%20in%20%22Isolation,by%20browsing%20the%20live%20repository.